# Gray or grey? I'm really not sure

Tags: word-usage, spelling, transatlantic-differences

Pretty self-explanatory (I know this is a common question). I'm not sure. Can someone help me out?

Comment: There are many words which have different spellings in American and British English. Go through **[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences)** article, which lists out a few of them.

Answer (score 1):

Google says :

> Grey and gray are both accepted in the English language. They refer to
>   a color of a neutral tone between black and white, and can also be
>   used metaphorically to convey gloom and dullness. However, **gray** is the
>   more popular spelling in the **US**, while **grey** reigns supreme in the **UK**.